# How to disable and enable checkboxes with Kendo

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have grid table in that Im adding checkboxes by using kendo and now I want to disable one check box based upon comments which i have in grid itself. so please help to resolve it.

```
{ field: "Decline", tilte: commonLib.readMessageByUserLanguage(COLUMNTITLENAME.Decline), "template": "<input type=\"checkbox\" />" },
                    { field: "Item", tilte: commonLib.readMessageByUserLanguage(COLUMNTITLENAME.Item) },
                    { field: "PartID", title: commonLib.readMessageByUserLanguage(COLUMNTITLENAME.PartID) },
                    { field: "Description", title: commonLib.readMessageByUserLanguage(COLUMNTITLENAME.Description), width:'300px' },
                    { field: "SubPart", title: commonLib.readMessageByUserLanguage(COLUMNTITLENAME.SubPart) },
                    { field: "SubPartDescription", title: commonLib.readMessageByUserLanguage(COLUMNTITLENAME.SubPartDescription) },
                    { field: "BusinessPartner", title: commonLib.readMessageByUserLanguage(COLUMNTITLENAME.BusinessPartner) },
                    { field: "ReqDelTM", title: commonLib.readMessageByUserLanguage(COLUMNTITLENAME.ReqDelTM) },
                    { field: "EarDelTM", title: commonLib.readMessageByUserLanguage(COLUMNTITLENAME.EarDelTM) },
                    { field: "EarDelDate", title: "Ear Del Date", hidden: true },
                    { field: "Comments", title: commonLib.readMessageByUserLanguage(COLUMNTITLENAME.Comments) }
                ]
            });
```

Comment: What have you tried ? What's the problem exactly ?

Comment: I have some comments on the same grid u can see it in last field "comments". There will be number of comments so if suppose comment is "Good Condition" then I need to disable the check box decline which is the first field in same grid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
"template": "<input type=\"checkbox\" # if (checkComments(data.Comments)) { ##=disabled=\"disabled\" # } # />"
```

And in you must create a global function like:

```
let checkComments = function checkComments(comments) {
    return true; // Return true to disable
}
```

Comment: Hi, this is disabling entire row but i just want to disable a single cell that is check box. Please help me out .

Comment: @Zabi you need to change the contents of `checkComments` to better fit your needs !!!

Comment: Can u please help me how to add contents on checkComments.  I have lot of comments like (1)Condition is good (2)Condition is bad. If condition is good then i need to enable the decline check box or else I should disable for second comment.

Comment: @Zabi that is a matter of a simple condition. `comments` in the parameters is your `Comments` property. Just do the checking there. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else If you return `true`, the input will be *disabled* and `false` the otherwise.

Comment: thank you so much it is working fine. I am able to disable and enable it as per the condition.

Comment: @Zabi good! Don't forget to check the answer as the correct answer.

Comment: while I am adding new columns in grid data it is showing error like this "Cannot find specific language message, please contact Administrator ". How to rectify it. Please help me.

Comment: @Zabi create a new question with more info.